Why is the USB commuincation from a Pi 5 to Pi Pico slower than from Pi 4 to Pi Pico
I compared the data transmission rate from Pi 4 to Pi Pico with Pi 5 to Pi Pico and saw some differences which I would like to understand and - in best case - improve.
This is my code for the pico:
extern "C" {
    int stdio_usb_in_chars(char *buf, int length);
}

uint32_t bytes_read = 0;    
uint32_t num_reads = 0;    
char cdc_buffer[256];

bool dataAvailableCallback(struct repeating_timer *t) {
    printf("%lu %f\n", bytes_read, (float)bytes_read / num_reads);
    bytes_read = 0;
    num_reads = 0;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();

    struct repeating_timer timer;
    add_repeating_timer_ms(-1000, dataAvailableCallback, NULL, &timer);
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while(true) {
        bytesRead = stdio_usb_in_chars(cdc_buffer, sizeof(cdc_buffer));
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            bytes_read += bytesRead;
            num_reads++;   
        }    
    }
 }

I read as much data as possible from USB and print out the number of bytes read once per second.
On the Pi I use the script:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, struct, serial

out_data = bytes([x % 255 for x in range(0, 2048)])

with serial.serial_for_url(sys.argv[1], timeout = 1) as f:
    while True:
        f.write(out_data)
        f.flush()
        waiting = f.in_waiting
        if waiting > 0:
            data = f.read(waiting)
            print(data)

Example output for Pi 4:
b'511936 64.000000\r\n'
b'510592 64.000000\r\n'
b'506816 64.008080\r\n'
b'511424 64.000000\r\n'

Example output for Pi 5:
b'187584 64.000000'
b'\r\n'
b'190720 64.000000'
b'\r\n'
b'189824 64.000000'
b'\r\n'

The Pi 4 achieves a transmission rate of ca. 500 kByte/sec and the Pi 5 ca. 190 kByte/sec.
Why is the Pi 5 slower? How can I increase the transmission rate?

Consider researching on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ instead
